# Windows 11 Shortcut [WIN]+[A] not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

Normally pressing <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will toggle the Control Center (quick settings), but now it does nothing.

Tried this:

- troubleshooter
- sticky keys
- [https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-quick-settings-not-working/#:~:text=If%20the%20Action%20Center%20isn,Ctrl%20%2B%20Shift%20%2B%20Enter%20keys](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-quick-settings-not-working/#:%7E:text=If%20the%20Action%20Center%20isn,Ctrl%20%2B%20Shift%20%2B%20Enter%20keys).

Outside the box thinking, if there is another way to toggle the BT, that would work with a macro?

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is the problem? Win+A doesn't open Control Center, or some other shortcut doesn't enable / disable Bluetooth, no kbd shortcuts work, something else?

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** **Make sure CAPS Lock is off.**   WinKey + a gives control center, but WinKey + A gives nothing.  That may be the issue here. That is, you must use WinKey with small a and not capital A.

**(2)** **Run DISM / SFC** and Resart as well.

(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

(4) SFC /SCANNOW

(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

**(3)** **Make sure Windows 11 is right up to date.**